# Predicament with arrays and expansion

Tags: java, arrays, loops, counter

So I know that the java convention is to use ArrayList<> when it comes to expansions and many other applications. The typical array cannot expand. My java course is elementary so we are still reviewing over arrays right now. As much as I want to use an arraylist I cant. How do I make it to where I store only elements that satisfy the condition in my counter array?

```
public int[] above100Degrees()
   {
      int[] blazing = new int[temps.length];
      for( int i = 0; i < temps.length; i++ )
      {
         if( temps[i] > 100 )
         {
            blazing[i] = temps[i];
         }
      }
      return blazing;
   }
```

Output

```
The temperature above 100 degrees is:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   103 108 109
```

Comment: I think maybe you need to better outline the constraints of the problem, is it that you're only allowed to use arrays? Or that you're only allowed a set number of array allocations? What about other java collections?

Comment: I am only allowed to use arrays for this exercise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a loop to find how many are above 100 before assigning the array.

```
public int[] above100Degrees()
{
    int newArrayLength=0;
    for( int i = 0; i < temps.length; i++ )
    {
        if( temps[i] > 100 )
        {
            newArrayLength++;
        }
    }

    int[] blazing = new int[newArrayLength];
    int positionInNewArray = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < temps.length; i++ )
    {
        if( temps[i] > 100 )
        {
            blazing[positionInNewArray] = temps[i];
            positionInNewArray++;
        }
    }
    return blazing;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just count how many elements match your filter *first*, then create the array, then populate it. It means you'll need to go through the array twice, but there are no really nice alternatives unless you want to end up creating multiple arrays. So something like:

```
public int[] above100Degrees() {
    // First work out how many items match your filter
    int count = 0;
    // Are you allowed to use the enhanced for loop? It's not necessary, but it
    // makes things simpler.
    for (int temp : temps) {
        if (temp > 100) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    // Create an array of the right size...
    int[] ret = new int[count];

    // ... and populate it.
    int index = 0;
    for (int temp : temps) {
        if (temp > 100) {
            ret[index++] = temp;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Curse you for being 2 mins faster than me :)

Comment: I have learned enhanced for loop but we didnt go over it long enough. I dont feel comfortable using it

Comment: @PatGreens: I suggest you go back over it then - but otherwise you can always rewrite that code to use an explicit index and fetch from the array by index.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a [ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#Java)

```
resultString = "The temperature above 100 degrees is: ";
for(int i = 0; i < blazing.length; i++){
    resultString += blazing[i] != 0 ? blazing[i] : "";
}
```

Note:  This would require more memory than JonSkeets answer, but could potentially be more efficient.  If your expect your array length to get very large, go with JonSkeet's answer.  In other words, this won't scale well.

Comment: The method signature says it returns an `int[]`. How will this help the OP?

Comment: @Laf His output is in a different method, this would go there.

Comment: I think this is a good answer for PatGreens' other question, not this one.

Comment: @AntonH Why not both?

Comment: @patterned This question thread seems to be just about creating and using arrays (I'm guessing it's for a homework assignment of some sort). The other question was more about the 'toString' method, which you answer is suited for.

Comment: @AntonH I think my answer contributes to his understanding of arrays, as he will get a taste of memory consumption vs efficiency.

Comment: @patterned Fair enough. Honestly, if I hadn't seen his other question (with both methods), I would recommend your approach. But I supposed it was for homework, so didn't want to change too much. But I would then prefer `for (int temp : blazing) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

One way is to count things before setting up the array.  Another way is to set up the array first and keep track of the count, then create a new array:

```
public int[] above100Degrees()
   {
      int[] blazing = new int[temps.length];
      int count = 0;
      for( int i = 0; i < temps.length; i++ )
      {
         if( temps[i] > 100 )
         {
            blazing[count++] = temps[i];
         }
      }

      // At this point, `count` is the number of elements you're going to return;
      // and the first `count` elements of `blazing` hold those elements, while the
      // remaining elements of `blazing` are garbage

      int[] result = new int[count];
      for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
           result[i] = blazing[i];

      return result;
   }
```

This approach would be better if the condition you're testing for takes a lot of time to calculate (as opposed to `temps[i] > 100`, which hardly takes any time).  You could use `Arrays.copy` to create the result array, but if you can't use `ArrayList` you probably can't use `Arrays.copy` either.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is keeping the cells in `blazing` array for `i <= 100`; You need to ignore these and start populating from `i = 101`.

Comment: I'm looking at your reputation and assuming that you're suffering from caffeine deficiency syndrome or something ...